# Find two subspace $U$ and $W$ of the matrix space $M_{2\times2}$ such that $M_{2\times2} = U ⊕ W$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find two subspace $U$ and $W$ of the matrix space $M_{2\times2}$ such that $M_{2\times2} = U ⊕ W$.

---

I know that a matrix space of $2\times2$ order will be a matrix containing $4$ vector spaces. But how am I supposed to divide it in two different subspaces?

Answer (score 1):

You have infinitely many ways of doing that at your disposal. You can take, for instance,$$U=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b,c\in\mathbb R\right\}$$and$$V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of $M_{2 \times 2}$ in terms of $\Bbb{R}^4$ (they are isomorphic). Suppose you want two 2D planes in $\Bbb{R}^4$ such that they only have $\mathbf{0}$ vector in common and their sum gives you $\Bbb{R}^4$.

So start with standard basis vector $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3,\mathbf{e}_4\}$. Let $U=\text{span}(\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2\})=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $V=\text{Span}(\{\mathbf{e}_3,\mathbf{e}_4\})=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Then $U$ and $V$ satisfy the required conditions.

In terms of matrices the spaces will be
\begin{align*}
U&=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\, \Big| \, a,b \in \Bbb{R}\right\}\\
V&=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\, \Big| \, c,d \in \Bbb{R}\right\}
\end{align*}